# $PATH env is updating when commands are ran directly, but do not update the $PATH when ran inside a script

Tags: path, mermaid

I've recently started to work on Linux, so I might have missed basic things. I've created a user and working inside that user.
I'm trying to install mermaid_cli. For this I need to update the PATH by adding path to the globally installed Yarn packages' executables.
`yarn_global_bin=$(yarn global bin) yarn global add @mermaid-js/mermaid-cli export PATH="$PATH:$yarn_global_bin"`
When I run these commands directly in the terminal, it runs and the 'mmdc' command that I'm trying to execute works. But when I'm trying to run the same commands inside a script, the 'mmdc' command doesn't work (it is not recognized as a command - mmdc command not found) though the script itself runs properly, but the $PATH is not updating.

Tried several things including adding `#!/bin/bash` in the beginning of the script, running source command along with the above script etc. But couldn't fix this.